# subsetting data (years) into set intervals in R

Tags: r, subset

I would like to sort my data into set intervals (by decade) so I can create a frequency table for number of records per decade. Below is my data. You can pretty much ignore everything besides the rightmost column, the year.

[image]

I've tried using the cut function but it hasn't worked out for me. Is there a function in the dplyr package that I can use? The intervals would be 1910-1919, 1920-1929, and so on.

Comment: Is it not working ? can you mark as resolved ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `ntile (x,n)`?
It breaks the input vector into n buckets.

Or function `recode`from `library(car)`.

```
decade<-recode(year,"1910:1919='1';1920:1929='2';1930:1939='3';...")
```

Answer (score 0):

next time, please give data example we can use:

```
df <- data.frame(1910:1952)
```

you can do it with `cut`, you need to define the breaks before:

```
breaks <- seq(from = 1910, to = 2100, by = 10)
df$cutpoint <- cut(df$X,breaks=breaks, right=FALSE)
```

look at `help(cut)` for option about labelling.